# Gem Install Connection Issues in Hyper-V

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2010 VM running via Hyper-V.  I can connect to individual gems with a web browser from within the VM, however when I run gem install for any gem, the connection times out with the error I've pasted below.  The image is using a virtual switch - do you think this is causing the problem?  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>gem install rails -V
Error fetching remote data:             Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt f
ailed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of tim
e, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
Falling back to local-only install
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party di
d not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what might be missing is the proxy configuration (considering you can browse to rubygems.org)

You can use `--http-proxy` option in your `gem install` command or set `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

First you will need to obtain the proxy configuration, which most likely is in your web browser.

It should look like this:

```
http://host:port/
```

Or:

```
http://username:password@host:port/
```

You will need need to use it in `gem install`:

```
gem install rails --http-proxy=http://host:port/
```

Or you can avoid typing it everytime if you set it as environment variable:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://host:port/
gem install rails
```

You can see more details about this with `gem help install` documentation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that's super helpful.  Where would I find this information from within a VM?  The browser doesn't say anything about proxy settings, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RobVious I'm not sure, never used Windows Server 2010 to tell you the details. I would suggest you check your VM network configuration if is using NAT or bridged mode, that could help figure out these issues.